# US Income datasets at the Census Tract / Block Level

Tags: us-census, census, income

I am currently using www2.census.gov to get demographics data from the census and was wondering if there was a similar source that could offer me blocks / census tract level data on income.

I would like to stay away from american fact finder, unless someone knows of a way to download entire datasets using python.

The www2.census.gov source is really handy so if the data is there and I'm just overlooking that would be optimal.

Comment: i think this is in the census summary files?

Comment: I didn't see it in the census summary files. It would be great if they were cause I have a system to extract them already. What would they be listed as if they were in the Summary Files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the Decennial Census or the American Community Survey report income information at the block level. They do report it at the [block group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Census_block_group) and tract level.

The data is accessible in many ways. I like using the [Census API](https://www.census.gov/developers/). Here's data on aggregate income by blockgroups in a census tract in Jefferson County, Alabama

https://api.census.gov/data/2016/acs/acs5?get=NAME,B01001_001E,B19313_001E&for=block%20group:*&in=state:01%20county:073%20tract:000100

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the  [Justice Map](http://www.justicemap.org/index.php?gsLayer=income&gfLon=-96.94715996&gfLat=32.87541675&giZoom=4&) has an estimate for block level income data.